# Bootstrap 4 Alpha-6 Card Deck wrapping issue

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I have a small issue with card-decks in Bootstrap 4 Alpha-6. When the cards are wrapping around because the screen is not wide enough to make room for all the cards in the deck, the 1. card on "next line" is not left-justified but has a narrow left margin.

is it a Aplha-6 bug to be fixed?, if anyone has a solution please let me know. Thanks in advance.

[image]

```css
.card {
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

[class*="row"] {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    justify-content: center;
}

[class*="col-"] {
    background: #efefef;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding-top: .75rem;
    padding-bottom: .75rem;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" style="margin: 10px">
        <div class="card-deck">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try adding the class `clearfix` to the last card parent div.

Comment: So basically `<div class="card clearfix">`

Comment: Thanks Jason, but the whole idea is that the layout is responsive, so I don't know if and which card will wrap to the next row. A fast test showed no difference by adding the clearfix class as suggested.

Comment: Actually you'll want to create a new div above the `<div class"card"></div>` and add the class `clearfix`. Which *mildly* works.

In all honesty, Bootstrap 4 is still Alpha which means things may not work as desired in terms of the framework and grid. under normal circumstances, `clearfix` would've taken care of this issue no problem. Looks like they still have some bugs to workout. 

Good luck, Thomas.